# Why won't trim work as a callback for array_walk or array_map in PHP?

Tags: php, trim, array-map, array-walk

Why does my sample code result in the first string still having a trailing space?

```
$a=array('test_data_1 ','test_data_2');
array_walk($a, 'trim');
array_map('trim', $a);                    
foreach($a AS $b){
    var_dump($b);
}
```

> string(12) "test_data_1 " string(11) "test_data_2"

Answer (score 58, accepted):

First, array_walk is the wrong function for your purpose at all.

Second, array_map does not change the original array but returns the mapped array. So what you need is:

```
$a = array_map('trim', $a);
```

Comment: thanks, did miss what array_map was returning - but pealse could you specify why would you concider array_walk as a wrong function?

Comment: if you read the [manual](http://php.net/array-walk) you will see that array_walk just **calls** a function with each of the values (and keys) of an array. So it would have the same effect as: `trim('test_data_1 ', 0); trim('test_data_2 ', 1)` - no assignments, no side effects (and a wrong second parameter for trim, by the way). You *could* of course write your own function for array_walk, that then trims the actual array element.

Answer (score 4):

For `array_walk` to modify the items (values) in the array, the callback must be a function that takes its first parameter by reference and modifies it (which is not the case of plain `trim`), so your code would become:

```
$a=array('test_data_1 ','test_data_2');
array_walk($a, function (&$value) { $value = trim($value); }); // by-reference modification
// (no array_map)
foreach($a AS $b){
    var_dump($b);
}
```

Alternatively, with `array_map` you must reassign the array with the return value, so your code would become:

```
$a=array('test_data_1 ','test_data_2');
// (no array_walk)
$a = array_map('trim', $a); // array reassignment
foreach($a AS $b){
    var_dump($b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

array_map return a new array, try this

```
$a=array('test_data_1 ','test_data_2');
array_walk($a, 'trim');
$a = array_map('trim', $a);
foreach($a AS $b){
    var_dump($b);
}
```